# How do preincrements and postincrements in the same line work in C++?

Tags: c++

I was asked in a job interview what would the following code in C++ would output to screen:

```
int i = 3;
cout << (++i + i++ - ++i + i++);
return 0;
```

In my computer it outputs 9, but why? Is this undefined?

Comment: Pre increment increments variable value first and then process and post increment does first process then increment, here answer 9 is correct because 4 + 4 - 6 + 6 is evaluate to 8 but because of your last ++ operation which is still not evaluated is evaluated at last, hence it become 9.

Comment: @PramodGaikwad no that is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is system dependent. Behavior not defined because of that.
Here which will be computed first `++i` or `i++` is different. This is unspecified.